# Criterion for one open ball contained in another in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Claim:

For $x,x' \in \mathbb{R}^n$  $B(x,r) \subset B(x,r') \Leftrightarrow d(x,x')\leq r'-r$, where $d(x,x')$ is induced by the Euclidean norm.

So the one direction is easy.  I have tried to use contrapositive for $\Rightarrow$ (parameterizing a line going through $x,x'$ and going out to a point in $B(x,r)\setminus B(x',r')$) but it's messy and I don't feel good about it.  I was hoping for a pointer or two on how to approach it directly. Maybe using continuity of the norm but I'm not sure how to start out.  Any tips would be super appreciated.
Regards.

Comment: It sounds like you have the right idea with the contrapositive--consider the point on the line going through $x$, $x'$ which is $d(x, x') + r$ away from $x'$. How far is it from $x$?

Comment: nevermind, I'm silly...this was easy.

Comment: You must have a typo. $B(x,r)\subset B(x,r')$ has nothing to do with $x'$ and is equivalent to $r\leq r'$.